# Find first subset where sum of row group equals given value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    amount INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

I want SQL to give first combination of tests rows where names are equals and sum of amount test group with same name are equal to a given value

In other words.
If i have values

```
INSERT INTO test VAlUES
('a', 'name1', 1),
('b', 'name1', 2),
('c', 'name1', 3),
('d', 'name2', 1),
('e', 'name2', 2),
('f', 'name2', 5);
```

and want find all ids of tests where sum equal 3 the output should be

```
a,
b,
d,
e
```

or

```
c,
d,
e
```

Comment: (1) Your results and question don't make sense.  (2) SQL is not really the best solution for this type of problem.

Comment: Or? A query is expected to return one result, not one or another.